# Signal Input to Neural Network

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, neural-network, signals, signal-processing

Working on a new project using [AWS Machine Learning](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/), with the intent of detecting certain patterns in an input signal.  That is to say, the input to my model (neural network, decision tree, etc.) is a discrete signal with an unknown number of values, and my output is a known number of values.

I understand the theory behind traditional ML models such as neural networks, where a function is derived to map a known number of inputs to a known number of outputs.  This makes sense with the requirement that the data supplied to the AWS ML platform be [rows of CSV attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/understanding-the-data-format-for-amazon-ml.html).

**Is there a way use this platform, or ML models in general for this kind of signal processing, or is there a preprocessing technique I can use to derive a fixed number of input variables?**

For example, one I had in mind was to take a fourier transform of the time signal, and describe the signal in the frequency domain band limited to a reasonable range (effectively cutting down the signal to a fixed number of values).  Total shot in the dark though, I'm not an expert on ML or signal processing.

Answer (score 1):

For audio signals, one possible (common?) method of data engineering is to use MFCCs ([Mel Frequency Cepstrum Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)), for a set of short segments in time (windows) of audio data, as your ML input table.

Comment: Thank you - definitely something I will look into, as my data is similar in many ways to an audio signal.  One key difference is that there may only be a few hundred (or even fewer) data points, as opposed to the thousands per second in an audio signal - is that detrimental to this technique?